# SQLite 'BETWEEN' doesn't behave as expected

Tags: java, sqlite, jdbc

I'm trying to select all rows that fall between two column values. The values are UNIX Timestamps but the query isn't returning any rows at all. Why would that be?

Here's my code:

```
public static ArrayList<Appointment> getAppointments(long start, long end) {
    ArrayList<Appointment> appointments = new ArrayList<>();
    try {
        Statement stat = db.createStatement();
        System.out.println("\n" + start + "  ->  " + end);

        // debugging only
        try (ResultSet rs = stat.executeQuery("SELECT * FROM appointments;")) {
            while (rs.next()) {
                long time = rs.getLong("date");
                if (time >= start && time <= end) {
                    System.out.println("Should be adding to list");
                }
            }
        } // 

        try (ResultSet rs = stat.executeQuery("SELECT * FROM appointments WHERE date BETWEEN " + start + " AND " + end + ";")) {
            while (rs.next()) {
                System.out.println("ADDING");
                appointments.add(new Appointment(rs.getLong("date"), rs.getInt("duration")));
            }
        }
    } catch (SQLException ex) {
    }
    System.out.println(appointments);
    return appointments;
}
```

Where the table has three rows with these values:

```
1347390000000 15
1347461100000 30
1347469200000 45
```

And the output is:

```
date = 1347390000000 duration = 15
date = 1347461100000 duration = 30
date = 1347469200000 duration = 45

1350141222283  ->  1350746022283
[]

1349536422283  ->  1350141222283
[]

1348931622283  ->  1349536422283
[]

1348330422283  ->  1348931622283
[]

1347725622283  ->  1348330422283
[]

1347120822283  ->  1347725622283
Should be adding to list
Should be adding to list
Should be adding to list
[]

1346516022283  ->  1347120822283
[]
```

Comment: You're blindly catching your SQLExceptions. Don't do that. Put some code that at least reports what they are.

Comment: I omitted the catch code as it wasn't relevant to the question. As for the output, as far as I can tell it makes perfect sense. The [] is what is being returned by the method each time the search range changes (weekly).

Comment: +1 Back to the question, I'm not really sure what's going on because the query works on SQL Fiddle http://sqlfiddle.com/#!5/bd4d0/1

Comment: Everything is System.out now because out and err aren't synchronized, which is why the order was jumbled. Apologies for that. :) Interesting that it works on SQL Fiddle, I feel like it's a small detail that I'm missing somewhere.

Comment: Fair enough. I'm removing my comments now because they're just noise.

Comment: I've figured it out. I had to declare the data type of the columns. -_-

Comment: Maybe the "date" column is not defined as long in the database? This could cause unexpected behaviour.

Comment: I agree with @greuze: is the actual data type a long, if not, maybe you should use a PreparedStatement for your query and use setTimestamp() for setting the values in the BETWEEN condition

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to declare the data types of the columns.